# free action of group scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-schemes

Let $f: G \to G'$ be a homomorphism of group schemes.  Then we get a natural action of $G$ on $G'$, given on points by $(g,g') \mapsto f(g) \cdot g'$. Then it is claimed that this action is free if and only if $Ker(f)$ is trivial. I have problem seeing why this is true.

Recall that given an action $\rho: G \times G' \to G'$, we define the graph morphism
$$\psi = (\rho, pr_2): G\times G' \to G' \times G'$$
and $\rho$ is said to be *free* if $\psi$ is a monomorphism of schemes.

It's clear that on points, the map $(g, g') \to (f(g)g', g')$ is injective if and only if $ker(f)$ is trivial. I don't know what to do from here though.

Comment: What is the definition of a monomorphism? Isn't it just the conditon that map on functor of points is injective?

Comment: @user45878 Could you explain what you mean by "map on functor of points is injective", and why that is the same as being a monomorphism (whose definition is like, it's a monomorphism in the category of schemes)? For me being a monomorphism of schemes means diagonal embedding is isomorphism but I feel like that's not very useful here.

Comment: You write that it is clear that a certain map of points is injective iff the kernel is trivial. But this is precisely what it means for a map to be a categorical monomorphism.